# How can I check my textboxes for similar value

Tags: javascript

I have a query and I dont know how will I do it. I have 10 textboxes and I want to check if there is a same value upon clicking check and pops out an alert box saying for EX. (textbox1 is the same with textbox 9). My problem is I don't know how will I do it. Is there a short way to do it because what I've done so far is to compare it one by one. heres the code:

```
if( textbox1.value == textbox2.value){
    alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox2)
    }
    else if( textbox1.value == textbox3.value){
    alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox3)
    }
    else if( textbox1.value == textbox4.value){
    alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox4)
    }
```

and so on.. as I reached the comparison until textbox 10. could anyone help me about this and how to make it shorter? TIA

Comment: Create an array of the inputs, create a corresponding array of the values. Loop over the values for `length - 2` iterations. Splice out each member of the values, do an indexOf check on its value, then put it back in. If there's a duplicate (`indexOf != -1`), the related element is in the same index in the elements array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with jQuery. The code below can also handle multiple duplicated values.

Use a dictionary object and push the id into dict[val].

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var dict = new Object();
    $(".textbox").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (dict[val]==null) dict[val]=[];
        dict[val].push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    $(".textbox").each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (dict[val].length>1) alert(dict[val]);
        dict[val]=[];
    });
});
```

Check example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GqL7P/).

Comment: What do use here as the alert function?

Comment: @user3404341 The alert function's message can be changed to fit the need. In this case, 
`alert("The value of textboxes "+dict[val]+" are the same.");`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store all the values in the text box. For example, if you have 5 text boxes with the following information

box1 - Hello

box2 - Bye

box3 - Hello

box4 - Yes

box5 - Bye

This could be stored in a dictionary/json like this.

```
{
    "Hello":[1, 3],
    "Bye":[2,5],
    "Yes":[4]
}
```

Then you could iterate thru the dictionary and see which boxes have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

use switch like this

```
switch(textbox1.value) {
    eval('case'+ textbox2.value+':');
        alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox2");
        break;

    eval('case'+ textbox3.value+':');
        alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox3");
        break;

    eval('case'+ textbox4.value+':');
        alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox4");
        break;

    eval('case'+ textbox5.value+':');
        alert("the value in textbox1 is the same with textbox5");
        break;
}
```